# Ruby Semaphores?

Tags: ruby, mutex, semaphore

I'm working on an implementation of the "Fair Barbershop" problem in Ruby. This is for a class assignment, but I'm not looking for any handouts.  I've been searching like crazy, but I cannot seem to find a Ruby implementation of Semaphores that mirror those found in C.

I know there is Mutex, and that's great.  Single implementation, does exactly what that kind of semaphore should do.

Then there's Condition Variables.  I thought that this was going to work out great, but looking at these, they require a Mutex for every wait call, which looks to me like I can't put numerical values to the semaphore (as in, I have seven barbershops, 3 barbers, etc.).

I think I need a Counting Semaphore, but I think it's a little bizarre that Ruby doesn't (from what I can find) contain such a class in its core.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: What about this: http://www.imasy.or.jp/~fukumoto/ruby/semaphore.rb ?

Comment: With a few tweaks this appears to be exactly what I was looking for.  The Thread.critical stuff apparently doesn't work in 1.9, so I replaced that with a Thread.exclusive {} block. I still don't understand why this isn't a part of Ruby's core libraries, though.

Comment: The server for imasy.or.jp appears to be gone or down... anyone have an updated link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @x3ro for his link.  That pointed me in the right direction.  However, with the implementation that Fukumoto gave (at least for rb1.9.2) Thread.critical isn't available.  Furthermore, my attempts to replace the Thread.critical calls with Thread.exclusive{} simply resulted in deadlocks.  It turns out that there is a proposed Semaphore patch for Ruby (which I've linked below) that has solved the problem by replacing Thread.exclusive{} with a Mutex::synchronize{}, among a few other tweaks.  Thanks to @x3ro for pushing me in the right direction.

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/attachments/1109/final-semaphore.patch

Comment: When I try to access that page, I get a not-authorized error.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JRuby, you can import semaphores from Java as shown in [this article](http://blog.paracode.com/2012/09/07/pragmatic-concurrency-with-ruby/).

```
require 'java'

java_import 'java.util.concurrent.Semaphore'

SEM = Semaphore.new(limit_of_simultaneous_threads)
SEM.acquire #To decrement the number available
SEM.release #To increment the number available
```

Answer (score 2):

There's http://sysvipc.rubyforge.org/SysVIPC.html which gives you SysV semaphores. Ruby is perfect for eliminating the API blemishes of SysV semaphores and SysV semaphores are the best around -- they are interprocess semaphores, you can use SEM_UNDO so that even SIGKILLs won't mess up your global state (POSIX interprocess semaphores don't have this), and you with SysV semaphores you can perform atomic operations on several semaphores at once as long as they're in the same semaphore set.

As for inter-thread semaphores, those should be perfectly emulatable with Condition Variables and Mutexes. (See Bernanrdo Martinez's link for how it can be done).

Answer (score 1):

I also found this code:
https://gist.github.com/pettyjamesm/3746457

probably someone might like this other option.

Answer (score 1):

since concurrent-ruby is stable (beyond **1.0**) and is being widely used thus the best (and portable across Ruby impls) solution is to use its [`Concurrent::Semaphore`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/Semaphore.html) class

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be useful to mention the `Thread::Queue` in this context for others arriving at this question.

The `Queue` is a thread-safe tool (implemented with some behind-the-scenes synchronization primitives) that can be used like a traditional multi-processing semaphore with just a hint of imagination. And it comes preloaded by default, at least in ruby v3:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# hold_your_horses.rb
q = Queue.new
wait_thread = Thread.new{
  puts "Wait for it ..."
  q.pop
  puts "... BOOM!"
}

sleep 1
puts "... click, click ..."
q.push nil

wait_thread.join
```

And can be demonstrated simply enough:

```
user@host:~/scripts$ ruby hold_your_horses.rb
Wait for it ...
... click, click ...
... BOOM!
```

The [docs for ruby v3.1](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/Thread/Queue.html) say a `Queue` can be initialized with an `enumerable` object to set up initial contents but that wasn't available in my v3.0. But if you want a semaphore with, say, 7 permits, it's easy to stuff the box with something like:

```
q = Queue.new
7.times{ q.push nil }
```

I used the `Queue` to implement baton-passing between some worker-threads:

```
class WaitForBaton
  def initialize
    @q = Queue.new
  end
  def pass_baton
    @q.push nil
    sleep 0.0
  end
  def wait_for_baton
    @q.pop
  end
end
```

So that thread **task_master** could perform steps **one** and **three** with thread **little_helper** stepping in at the appropriate time to handle step **two**:

```
baton = WaitForBaton.new
task_master = Thread.new{
  step_one(ARGV[0])
  baton.pass_baton
  baton.wait_for_baton
  step_three(logfile)
}

little_helper = Thread.new{
  baton.wait_for_baton
  step_two(ARGV[1])
  baton.pass_baton
}

task_master.join
little_helper.join
```

Note that the `sleep 0.0` in the `.pass_baton` method of my `WaitForBaton` class is necessary to prevent **task_master** from passing the baton to itself: unless thread scheduling *happens* to jump away from **task_master** right after `baton.pass_baton`, the very next thing that happens is **task_master**'s `baton.wait_for_baton` - which takes the baton right back again. `sleep 0.0` explicitly cedes execution to any other threads that might be waiting to run (and, in this case, blocking on the underlying `Queue`).

Ceding execution is not the default behavior because this is a somewhat unusual usage of semaphore technology - imagine that **task_master** could be generating many tasks for **little_helper**s to do and **task_master** can efficiently get right back to generating tasks right after passing a task off through a `Thread::Queue`'s `.push([object])` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other links here aren't working for me, I decided to quickly hack something together.  I have not tested this, so input and corrections are welcome.  It's based simply on the idea that a Mutex is a binary Semaphore, thus a Semaphore is a set of Mutexes.

https://gist.github.com/3439373